# is :hover really needed for cusor?

Tags: css, hover

was doing some css work and had a list of elements that needed a cursor: pointer attribute.

Whilst doing this it occurred to me, adding :hover seems pointless as the style targets the element anyway and will change your cursor based on the attribute value. I did a test and removing :hover showed me that I didn't really need it - but was just curious as to whether there is a downside to not including :hover?

Comment: If you style the main element with the pointer then you do not need to re-add it specifically for the hover.  The hover is only for if you want to change / overwrite any of the styles on hover

Comment: No, there really is no point in setting cursor in :hover. This is actually the first time I've heard anyone do this.

Answer (score -2):

The **:hover** selector is used to select elements when you mouse over them.

You can follow this syntax:

```
:hover {
    css declarations;
}
```

For Example:

```
a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

this can be used in almost every element. please see details here -

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp